# Did bridge consoles explode in TOS?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tos

I haven't seen much Star Trek TOS in quite a long time, but I am pretty sure I remember consoles on the bridge exploding - or at least throwing sparks, making noise and injuring crew. See this [question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/7511/51174) and [answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/95241/51174) for reference.

For this question let's limit to consoles on the Enterprise's or other Starfleet vessels' bridge, and maybe at the navigation station of a shuttlecraft. It seems I'm assuming here that on the bridge at least those were *controls* the actual power being activated, shunted, etc was elsewhere.

**Are there any episodes of TOS where a bridge console explodes? Bonus points if it injured someone.**

Comment: Oh, I see. You're asking **"in which episode/s of TOS did a bridge console explode? "**. Right. Gotcha.

Comment: @Richard that would be a bonus for sure - *if* it happened, which I don't know yet. An answer in the positive would probably bring at least one example, but if I ask "which episodes" I'm scared that it will be considered asking for a list and I got called on that once already :) so I'm trying to be *really careful* by simply asking for a boolean.

Comment: Nah, if it's a question of something being ***notably rare***, asking in which episodes it happened is perfectly acceptable.

Comment: _"Bonus points if it injured someone."_ Hehehe

Comment: Console/firework storage lockers, I assume you mean.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As you can see, the consoles did indeed explode in TOS

[image]
<sub><sup>**TOS: Where No Man Has Gone Before**</sup></sub>

And for the bonus point (which I'll have to share with [Hypnosifl](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/126047/did-bridge-consoles-explode-in-tos/126058?noredirect=1#comment315065_126058)) we have someone getting injured by an exploding console...

[image]
<sub><sup>**TOS: City on the Edge of Forever**</sup></sub>

Comment: Aha, the pilot! (I mean pilot episode, not the person). Wow, I want that GIF as my desktop!

Comment: Technically Charlie gets zapped a few seconds afterwards, but that's not really a console effect.

Comment: Oh - Charlie!  It's not the pilot-pilot, got it. It's the "you wouldn't like me when I'm angry" episode.

Comment: Oh, the very pilot. I've never seen the first half for whatever reason :P These do look like the kinds of explosions you get from real computers, though, rather than the TNG-style "plasma bursts" :D

Comment: @Luaan ya, that appears to be actual fire - real flames at one point. Doesn't happen in studios very often these days.

Comment: I guess the technology to make [optical isolators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opto-isolator) was lost during WWIII.

Comment: The clip is from "Where No Man Has Gone Before" - the second pilot, (third episode to air). 

Charlie is not in this episode. He is in (air order), Episode 2 "Charlie X"
The first pilot was called "The Cage" and was not aired in original form, but was re-edited into the two-part episode "The Menagerie"

Comment: Just to show this wasn't the sole example in TOS, [here's a shot from City on the Edge of Forever](http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/File%3aExplosion_in_sulus_face.jpg).

Comment: @Hypnosifl excellent! TOS bridge consoles explode and can also cause injury. I *thought* so, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

They caught fire as well:

[@blobbymcblobby's comment](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/250413/bridge-lights-dimming-or-changing-color-after-battle-stations-was-declared-on?noredirect=1#comment686451_250413) links to the YouTube video clip [Star Trek III The Search For Spock - The Enterprise's Encounter With The Klingon Bird Of Prey](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_hvh2oFBkEk) and after the Enterprise is hit by a Kingon Bird of Prey we can see smoke between Scotty and Sulu followed by [Bunsen burner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bunsen_burner)-like flames between them.

[image: screen shot from Star Trek III The Search For Spock - The Enterprise's Encounter With The Klingon Bird Of Prey] [image: screen shot from Star Trek III The Search For Spock - The Enterprise's Encounter With The Klingon Bird Of Prey]

[image: screen shot from Star Trek III The Search For Spock - The Enterprise's Encounter With The Klingon Bird Of Prey] [image: screen shot from Star Trek III The Search For Spock - The Enterprise's Encounter With The Klingon Bird Of Prey]