# Bridge lights dimming or changing color after "battle stations!" was declared on some ship in Star Trek TOS?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tos, object-identification

I seem to remember the lighting on the bridge of some ship<sup>1</sup> in *Star Trek* TOS<sup>2</sup> changing *by design* from normal to something attention-getting when "battle stations!" was announced. Changes in color, intensity or perhaps even direction.

But I can't place what I'm remembering exactly, or on what ship it took place.

I do seem to remember the *Enterprise's* bridge's lights dimming for a moment only when photon torpedoes were launched, and perhaps this happened ship-wide.

**Question:** But was there ever a lighting change that lasted longer, and that represented *by design* a transition to or from a "battle stations!" situation?

<sup>1</sup>Romulan or Klingon perhaps?

<sup>2</sup>I am primarily interested in (and remembering) The *original television series* but am reminded that the [tos](/questions/tagged/tos) tag also covers the series of movies based on it as well, so answers about the films are certainly allowed as it's too late to specify only the original TV series (an answer has been posted). In meta: [Does the use of [star-trek-tos] include or exclude TOS-era films?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10351/51174)

Comment: Don't think it would have been Romulan. I think we only ever see inside a Romulan ship in a single episode

Comment: @SpacePhoenix Make that two episodes: Balance of Terror and The Enterprise Incident.

Comment: My gut feeling is that any changes are either flashes on the view screen from explosions and weapons fire. Power being lost by the ship or power being drained for use elsewhere in the ship

Comment: @SpacePhoenix I will *wait a while* to see if there are any further answers here, and then consider a new question not restricted to the TOS world. "Has any SciFi TV show..." or something along those lines perhaps.

Comment: From what I have seen, as @SpacePhoenix says, bridge lighting changes are from external influences and cast close ups getting dramatic lighting shots. Battle stations seems to be only represented by pulsing red panels and audio. Aside from TWOK, which does it right imho, even TNG movies do not change bridge lighting much (keeping it already moody dark, as in [ST:Nemesis] (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f5HQ1xF6pxo) ). Outside of Star Trek, reboot BSG again did not change the bridge much but [1978 BSG] (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Eo47AVLuRvM) got it right.

Comment: ah, i was editing the above comment but timed out - apologies - Again, outside of Star Trek, this 1978 BSG clip shows long duration difference between [Condition I (Battle Stations) on Galactica and Condition III (Wartime cruising) on Atlantia][1].

[1]: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4RShAMFvnFM

Comment: Have to check but iirc on the Enterrprise E some of the bridge lighting gets dimmed during red alert situations (better contract of displays for the crew?)

Comment: Actually it probably does, the clip i saw might have been after it was already dimmer. Voyager eps Year in Hell, Equinox (their bridge dimmed too), etc all show the bridge dimmed for very long periods of time at battle stations.

Comment: Just watching https://youtu.be/_hvh2oFBkEk - "Star Trek III The Search For Spock - The Enterprise's Encounter With The Klingon Bird Of Prey" - Enterprise bridge goes entirely red on Red Alert, Klingon Bridge is dark when cloaked, and goes brighter when de-cloaking.

Comment: @blobbymcblobby Bingo! You've got an answer; right there at `01:20` "Red alert Mr. Scott" and *voila* the Enterprise bridge primary lighting changes from white to red. :-)

Comment: its been good revisiting clips from the good old days! :)

Answer (score 3):

just going off the top of my head here..

(thought at 0:11, Spock appears to be on the bridge and the lighting is very different)

So, from above, and from memory, and guessing, I would say the bridge lighting was kept fairly static (going by studio lighting, I would assume once it was set up nicely with highlights, bounces, flags etc, they would not want to disturb it).

When it comes to red alert, this is shown by backdrop light panels going red (and pulsing slowly) and the usual sound effects.

Any other lighting effects seem to come from whoever or whatever they are in aggressive contact with (see the blue light and flashes in the video links above).

As for fluctuations on photon torpedo launch, look at Balance of Terror:

at 2:32

(engineering gets the light dip on launch)

at 1:31

The bridge gets the light dip too.

In fact this episode shows that the light changes on the bridge only really happen when they get to combination main talent medium close up or for main character close up - the background lighting is generally untouched but they've flagged, highlighted and modelled the faces of the characters that matter in those shots - for more dramatic effect, which really makes no sense in the real world.

What's great about this is that the Romulan set is built and lit like a U-boat - no surprise given it is apparently based upon a great World War 2 US warship vs German submarine movie, 1957's 'The Enemy Below' starring Robert Mitchum and ‎Curt Jurgens.

Outside of that, again it is engineering that really gets a lighting effect:

at 1:06

IIRC, wasn't there something about the inside of the Klingon ships not being seen until TMP?

To my thinking, if someone said TOS, I can only think of the tv series and perhaps the cartoon series based on the same time period and characters.

tbh,
I treat the films separately, if only because production techniques and designs were so very different from the series that they were a whole new generation for me (and, the best, for me too).

Comment: It's kind of a cheat, but you could argue that we saw the inside of a D-7 in "The Enterprise Incident" - it just happened to be a Romulan one.

Comment: Aye! Absolutely, very true!

Answer (score 0):

This is common in Star Trek, actually. [Here's an example from Voyager](https://youtu.be/1Bh6rteqVpY?t=65), with the bridge going from fairly well-lit to dark with red highlights. There's also a rare [blue alert](https://youtu.be/K5WJ7tiem3A?t=47) in TNG when Data cuts off the life support.

Since you tagged this with TOS, you're probably more interested in the bridge scenes from the films. [Here's the "battle stations" effect in Wrath of Khan](https://youtu.be/v7Xmh-weq1g?t=70).

Comment: Thanks! I'm actually most interested in the television series from the late 1960's (the "S" standing for "series" but I forgot that "TOS" without clarification can also cover the "series" of movies that followed that series with most of the same cast, so since I didn't explicitly restrict to television series an answer about this film will also apply. I'll add a clarifying comment to this effect to the question.

Comment: I just love that battle stations effect in TWOK - in fact l love just about everything on TWOK.